# How to reload a page with combobox (select) value?

Tags: php, javascript, select, combobox

I have a combobox - `combo1`. Everytime a change the combobox value, I should have a button that submits that value and reloads the page. I want to start at `mysite/value?v=1` and end with `mysite/value?v=2`. This is what I have so far:

**Javascript**:

```
function nav() {
    var selObj = document.getElementById("combo1");
    valor = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;
    // reload the page
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="button" onclick="nav()" value="Ok" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `window.location`:

```
function nav(){
    var selObj = document.getElementById("combo1");

    valor = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location = 'mysite/value?v=' + valor;
}
```